# Show that $u_n$ converges if $\frac{1-(1+\frac{u_n}{n})^{-n}}{u_n}$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I recently contracted a loan and was curious about how interest rates were calculated. This question arises when one wants to compute the limit of the annual percentage rate of a loan as the compounding periods go to 0:

Let $(u_n)_n$ be a positive and bounded sequence such that $\frac{1-(1+\frac{u_n}{n})^{-n}}{u_n}$ converges. Show that $u_n$ converges.

I intuitively think it is true but I cannot prove or disprove it. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v_n=[1-(1+u_n/n)^{-n}]/u_n$ and $v=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}v_n$.

For any convergent subsequence of $(u_n)$ we have $$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}u_{n_k}=u\implies\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}v_{n_k}=f(u):=\begin{cases}(1-e^{-u})/u,&u>0\\\hfill 1,\hfill&u=0\end{cases}.$$

Thus, if $\underline{u}=\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}u_n$ and $\overline{u}=\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}u_n$, then $f(\underline{u})=f(\overline{u})\color{gray}{[{}=v]}$.

But the function $f(u)$ is strictly decreasing: for $u>0$ $$f'(u)=\frac{(1+u)e^{-u}-1}{u^2}<0\impliedby 1+u<e^u,$$ hence we must have $\underline{u}=\overline{u}$.

Comment: How do you know that $ \liminf u_{n} > 0 $ ?

Comment: @SotArmen: *now* corrected ;)

Comment: Great, now seems correct to me, let me just check where there is a gap in mine because we don't agree.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, that is perfect

Comment: For those wondering (like me for a while) why $v_{n_k} \to f(u)$: this is because $(1+x/n)^n \to e^x$ _uniformly_ over any compact set.

Answer (score 1):

Deonte the limit of $x_{n} = \frac{1-(1+\frac{u_{n}}{n})^{n}}{u_{n}}$ by $L$. Notice that $L$ must be $ \geq 0 $ as $u_{n}$ is positive.

You can rewrite $x_{n}$ and $u_{n}$ in the following manner:

$$ (1+\frac{u_{n}}{n})^{-n} + u_{n}x_{n}-1  = 0  $$

As $u_{n}$ is bounded the $\liminf u_{n}$ and $\limsup u_{n}$ are finite. Consider subsequences $a_{n_{k}} $ and $b_{n_{k}}$ such that:

$$ u_{a_{n_{k}}} \rightarrow  \liminf u_{n} = l_{1}$$

and

$$ u_{b_{n_{k}}} \rightarrow \limsup u_{n} = l_{2}$$

Using the above relation for these subsequences, due to a well known lemma:

$$(1+\frac{u_{a_{n_{k}}}}{n})^{-n} \rightarrow e^{-l_{1}} $$

and similarly for the $\limsup$ we thus get that we must have:

$$ e^{-l_{i}}+ Ll_{i} - 1 = 0 , i = 1,2$$

consider the function $f(x) = e^{-x}+Lx-1 $ we are interested in the case that $x \geq 0 $ as $u_{n}$ is positive. Then f clearly has a zero at $0$ and its derivative is equal to:

$$ f'(x) = L-e^{-x}$$

1st case: If $L\geq 1$ we get that $f(x)$ is increasing for positive $x$ and thus the only zero of $f$ is $0$ for $x \geq 0 $. Thus we get that $u_{n} \rightarrow 0 $ if $x_{n} \rightarrow L \geq 1 $

2nd case: If $0 \leq L < 1 $ then $f$ has two zeroes for $x \geq 0 $ , $0$ and some $x_{0}$. If however $\liminf u_{n} = 0$ and $\limsup u_{n} = x_{0}$ from the starting relation considering $a_{n_{k}}$ we have that $\lim x_{n} = 1 $ which is  a contradiction. Thus in that case $\liminf u_{n} = \limsup u_{n} $ and $u_{n}$ converges.

edit: added a point on the 2nd case.